# How can I format an integer to a two digit hex?

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to get a chr to hex conversion where the output is always two digits?

for example, if my conversion yields 0x1, I need to convert that to `0x01`, since I am concatenating a long hex string.

The code that I am using is:

```
hexStr += hex(ord(byteStr[i]))[2:]
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can use string formatting for this purpose:

```
>>> "0x{:02x}".format(13)
'0x0d'

>>> "0x{:02x}".format(131)
'0x83'
```

**Edit**: Your code suggests that you are trying to convert a string to a hexstring representation.  There is a much easier way to do this (Python2.x):

```
>>> "abcd".encode("hex")
'61626364'
```

An alternative (that also works in Python 3.x) is the function `binascii.hexlify()`.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, except that I had to drop the 0x from the beginning, since all I wanted was the part after that.

Comment: Also note that if you want 0x0D vs 0x0d use X vs x in format string, ie, `"0x{:02X}".format(13)`

Comment: `"0x{:02x}".format(239557639)` result
`'0xe475c07'` wrong

Answer (score 21):

You can use the format function:

```
>>> format(10, '02x')
'0a'
```

You won't need to remove the `0x` part with that (like you did with the `[2:]`)

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice idea. However, I can't get it work since my output is a string, and this seems to work only for integers. I'm pretty new to python. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The string could be casted into an integer in the following manner format(string("10"), '02x')

Answer (score 11):

If you're using python 3.6 or higher you can also use fstrings:

```
v = 10
s = f"0x{v:02x}"
print(s)
```

output:

```
0x0a
```

The syntax for the braces part is identical to `string.format()`, except you use the variable's name.  See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ for more.

Comment: This is useful, particularly when we don't need print, but as strings to manipulate.

Answer (score 6):

```
htmlColor = "#%02X%02X%02X" % (red, green, blue)
```

Answer (score 4):

The standard module `binascii` may also be the answer, namely when you need to convert a longer string:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify('abc\n')
'6162630a'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) instead of using the hex function:

```
>>> mychar = ord('a')
>>> hexstring = '%.2X' % mychar
```

You can also change the number "2" to the number of digits you want, and the "X" to "x" to choose between upper and lowercase representation of the hex alphanumeric digits.

By many, this is considered the old %-style formatting in Python, but I like it because the format string syntax is the same used by other languages, like C and Java.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way (I think) is:

```
your_str = '0x%02X' % 10
print(your_str)
```

will print:

```
0x0A
```

The number after the % will be converted to hex inside the string, I think it's clear this way and from people that came from a C background (like me) feels more like home

Comment: I would note that the output using your_str = '0x%02X,' % 10 has a comma in it.  0x0A,

Comment: That's true, I must have copied it from some code I was working and didn't clean it very well. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: I actually found that example useful because I wanted a comma :)