# Formatting hex to be printed with 2 digits?

Tags: python, hex

The built-in function hex() in python returns me a number in the form 0xf or 0x0 but i want them as 0x00. I found [this on the python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) but dont really know how to interpret it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string formatting for this purpose:

```py
>>> "0x{:02x}".format(13)
'0x0d'
```

More detailed examples here:

[How can I format an integer to a two digit hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676864/how-can-i-format-an-integer-to-a-two-digit-hex)

Answer (score 3):

In python3, use this `f` string format:

```
f"0x{variable:02x}"
```

For maximum python2/3 compatibility, use `.format()`:

```
"0x{:02x}".format(variable)
```