# Python:Hex conversion value is not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python programming and facing some issue with formating of the extracted 32 bit CRC from the file.
I want the CRC to be stored in another file, where the format of storing should be 0x2C, 0x9F, 0x0D, 0xE0

when I am running this below code, I am getting the output stored in ApplicationData1.crc as 0x2c , 0x9f, 0xd, 0xe08 and also the third byte is 0xd which should be **0x0D** and fourth byte is 0xe08 which should be **0xE0**, can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or what can be tried out?

Whenever I am running the code it goes through two iterations and printing the integer values as below:

```
a4, a3, a2, a1, checksum:
88, 149, 192, 178, 2998965592
224, 13, 159, 44, 748621280
```

```
import zlib
def crc32(filename="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ApplicationData.bin", chunksize=65536):
    with open(filename, "rb") as f1:
        checksum = 0
        while (chunk := f1.read(chunksize)) :
            checksum = zlib.crc32(chunk, checksum)
            file = open('ApplicationData1.crc', "w")
            print(hex(checksum))
            checksum_hex=hex(checksum)
            a4 = (checksum & 0xff)
            a3 = (checksum >> 8) & 0xff
            a2 = (checksum >> 16) & 0xff
            a1 = checksum >> 24
            print(hex(a3))
            file.write('%s , %s, %s, %s' % (hex(a1), hex(a2), hex(a3), hex(a4)))
crc32()
```

Comment: Can you provide a verifiable example? I.e. give us an input so we can replicate the error. Off hand it looks like you just need to format the hex to use two digits when you do the `file.write(...)`.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11676895/8150685) as a reference,

Comment: "fourth byte is 0xe08" - That can't be true, bytes don't hold such large values.

Comment: I am getting the output as 0x2c , 0x9f, 0xd, 0xe08 in the file.Still not understanding the stuff!!But its true

Comment: with Debug checksum printing in the code on the console I am getting output as below :0xb2c09558
0x95
0x2c9f0de0
0xd

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse: I tried from that post, Still I am getting the same issue.I can share the input file as I am working with official file.But  my problem is when I get any hex value of two bytes such as in this case its just D and no 1st byte, then I want to add to file insted of 0xd as 0x0D, anything I can update in this file?

Comment: I dont want the full file. Can you make your own input that causes the issues? Just create a short string that causes the same issue and we can help you solve it from there.

Comment: Also `0xe08` is actually `0x0E 0x08`. `hex()` does not limit to a single byte, its just the same formatting issue you are currently having.

Comment: How about this. Can you print the integer values from `a4, a3, a2, a1` and add those? As well as print the `checksum` value and paste that. With those I can help you.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: Whenever I am running the code it goes through two iterations and printing the integer values as below starting from a4, a3, a2, a1 and checksum :88
149
192
178
2998965592
224
13
159
44
748621280

Comment: Can you please add the below content to ApplicationData.bin and save it and try to generate the  output: I am getting the output as 0x2 , 0x1e, 0x25, 0xb5 which I am expecting in the format of 0x02 , 0x1e, 0x25, 0xb5                                    ÎÅDˆ;·Fæèîè†T·ÅFV·Å0ö·Tk‚íƒæè#‡l€æ‚î€·TQäè"íè kêæ‚kè0
êÄæêÄ€…=;œ²aÌ I aí„ìè„?Î  Ã€ $l‚n€·FÌ ªl@í„æèíè kêÆ€kêì„úÖí„íè ê Æ kêÌ G í„íè êÆkêÌ H ‡Çî„l†=;˜·FìHlèìJlèíˆìèlèN†ìL wæèîè†T·ÅFV·Å0ö·Tíè kè0íˆìè„?Î  Ã€ $l‚n€·Fì@íˆlèíè@íˆìèîè¬ '
ì lèÌ b -ìèÃ lè$bè&bènèì†ƒ l†ì„Â ‚ l„&…ì†&lDŠ=;œ·Fìèlèí„ìHlèìJlèN‚ìL jæèîè†T·ÅFV·Å0ö·Tíè áè0'ì„úþ^a Ì iî„l ì„Bí„lD'

Comment: edit your question and put this information there. I can replicate the `0xd` issue (which I can fix) but I don't see the `0xe08`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: I have edited the question as said byb you and in the previous comment I have given some details of the file too.If any more inputs required let me know.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: But I will be unaware of the data = [
  [88, 149, 192, 178, 2998965592],
  [224, 13, 159, 44, 748621280]
] as I will running the script many times on different files and it should be generic, How I will be knowing this data in advance until printed on the console, any other thing to avoid this data part in the script ?

Comment: Thats fine. Change my example to meet your code. Open your file with a `with` clause, and use the string formatting like I do instead of using `%`. See if that works. If it fails, give me the inputs it fails with.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: Thank you so much!! Its working as expected!!!!Great help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can fix the `0xd` issue using string formatting. I can't replicate your `0xe08` issue. It could be because you are opening your file but never closing it.

This fixs your `0xd` issue. See if it fixes your other issue as well:

```
data = [
  [88, 149, 192, 178, 2998965592],
  [224, 13, 159, 44, 748621280]
]
with open('output.crc', 'w') as out_file:
    for a4, a3, a2, a1, checksum in data:
        r = "0x{:02X}, 0x{:02X}, 0x{:02X}, 0x{:02X}".format(a1, a2, a3, a4)
        # or with f-string f"0x{a1:02X}, 0x{a2:02X},0x{a3:02X}, 0x{a4:02X}"
        out_file.write(r + '\n')
```

output.crc:

```
0xB2, 0xC0, 0x95, 0x58
0x2C, 0x9F, 0x0D, 0xE0
```