# Python: converting base 10 to base 36

Tags: python, base36

I'm trying to convert decimal to base 36 (...8,9,a,b,c...x,y,z,10,11...) but when I run my code I get a bunch of floats instead of integers.

```
def trc(n):
    if (n < 0): print(0, end='')
    elif (n<=1): print(n, end='')
    else:
        trc( n / 36 )
        x =(n%36)
        if (x < 10): print(x, end='')
        else: print(chr(x+87), end='')
```

I based this code off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796238/python-convert-decimal-to-hex).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181919/python-base-36-encoding this one

Comment: Need integer division in Python3, `trc(n // 36)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3, the `/` operator does floating point division, even when both arguments are integers. This is a change from Python 2, where dividing two integers would discard the fractional part.

You can explicitly request integer division by using the `//` operator. The result will be rounded towards negative infinity. Or, since you're also calculating the modulus, you could use `divmod` to get them both at the same time:

```
else:
    n, x = divmod(n, 36)
    trc(n)
    if x < 10: # ...
```

Comment: I notice that a lot of the homework questions recently are from Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

You could just do this:

```
def trc(n):
    return(int(str(n), base = 36))
```

Then `print(trc(x))` to get `x` in base 36. This solution works for any base.

However it doesn't give you the letters of base 36: instead of 'z' it returns 36.

You would need to make a seperate program for that.

It should be good enough in most cases, unless you're working with something like **excel** that needs the letters.

Comment: This is the wrong direction from what the question is asking.