# Why Does Hex() Function returns a string instead an int hex?

Tags: python, string, int, hex, ascii

I dont know why Hex function returns a string like '0x41' instead 0x41

[image]

I need to convert an ASCII value into a hex. But i want in 0x INT format, not into a '0x' string.

```
ascii = 360
hexstring = hex(ascii)
hexstring += 0x41  # i cant do this because hexstring is a string not a int hex
```

How i can get a int hex??
thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no int hex object. There is only an *alternative syntax* to create integers:

```
>>> 0x41
65
```

You could have used `0o1010` too, to get the same value. Or use `0b1000001` to specify it in binary; they are all *the exact same numeric value* to Python; they are all just different forms to specify an integer value in your code.

Simply keep `ascii` as an integer and sum your hex notation values with that:

```
>>> ascii = 360
>>> ascii += 0x41
>>> ascii
425
```

`hex()` produces a string that can be interpreted by a Python program in the same manner, and is usually used when debugging code or quick presentation output (but you should use `format(number, 'x')` if you want to produce end-user output without the `0x` prefix). It is not needed to work with integers.